# Placing the constant when defining a matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, matrix

Can someone explain to me why  these seemingly same pieces of code yield different results in using my function on test data from a MNIST dataset('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/')?

1

```
def fit_generative_model1(x,y):
   k = 10  # labels 0,1,...,k-1
   d = (x.shape)[1]  # number of features
   mu = np.zeros((k,d))
   sigma = np.zeros((k,d,d))
   pi = np.zeros(k)

   for label in range(0,k):
       c = 4000
       indices = (y == label)
       mu[label] = np.mean(x[indices,:], axis=0)
       sigma[label] = np.cov(x[indices,:], rowvar=0, bias=1) + c*np.identity(784, dtype=float) # regularizing the matrix
   return mu, sigma, pi

mu, sigma, pi = fit_generative_model1(train_data, train_labels)
```

2

```
def fit_generative_model2(x,y):
   k = 10  # labels 0,1,...,k-1
   d = (x.shape)[1]  # number of features
   mu = np.zeros((k,d))
   sigma = np.zeros((k,d,d))
   pi = np.zeros(k)
   for label in range(0,k):
       indices= (y==label)
       mu[label]= np.mean(x[indices,:],axis=0)
       sigma[label]= np.cov(x[indices,:], rowvar=0, bias=1) + 4000*np.eye(784) #Regularized
       pi[label]= float(sum(indices))/float(len(y))        
  
   return mu, sigma, pi

mu, sigma, pi = fit_generative_model2(train_data, train_labels)
```

Next, making predictions on the test data.

```
# Compute log Pr(label|image) for each [test image,label] pair.
k = 10
score = np.zeros((len(test_labels),k))
for label in range(0,k):
    rv = multivariate_normal(mean=mu[label], cov=sigma[label])
    for i in range(0,len(test_labels)):
        score[i,label] = np.log(pi[label]) + rv.logpdf(test_data[i,:])
predictions = np.argmax(score, axis=1)
# Finally, tally up score
errors = np.sum(predictions != test_labels)
print("Your model makes " + str(errors) + " errors out of 10000")
print("This is " + str(errors/100) + "% error rate")

#with model1 -??
Your model makes 9020 errors out of 10000
This is 90.2% error rate


#with model2  - all good.
Your model makes 431 errors out of 10000
This is 4.31% error rate
```

I am also struggling to make the loop to work for the best c.

```
for c in [20,2000, 4000]:
    k = 10 
    score = np.zeros((len(test_labels),k))
    for label in range(0,k):
        rv = multivariate_normal(mean=mu[label], cov=sigma[label])
        for i in range(0,len(test_labels)):
            score[i,label] = np.log(pi[label]) + rv.logpdf(test_data[i,:])
    predictions = np.argmax(score, axis=1)
    errors = np.sum(predictions != test_labels)

    print("Model with  "+ str(c) + " has a " + str(errors/100) + " error rate")

Model with  20 has a 4.31 error rate
Model with  2000 has a 4.31 error rate
Model with  4000 has a 4.31 error rate
```

Comment: The first function doesn't change 'pi' at all, leaving it as all zeros. Is that intentional?

Comment: well spotted, its pi that makes the difference! my code was the first one. " pi[j]: the frequency of that label". thank you.